# Hi I was wondering if there is any algebraic way to find the zeroes of a cos/sin formula without using the unit circle?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I understand how to find the zeroes using the unit circle or just graphing it for any matter for my equation.

I was just wondering if there is a **formula** or an **algebraic** way I could find them.

Here's the equation that I stumbled upon -3cos(x+pi/2),

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Do you mean $-3\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$? Assuming that's the equation you want to solve, do you know what values of $u$ give $\cos u = 0$, and if so, could you please explain in more detail where you're stuck? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking if there's some formula akin to the quadratic formula that's used for equations of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$, but in this case for $-3\cos(x-\frac\pi2)=0$.

No, not really. Andrew Hwang's comment is along the lines of what you should be thinking in this scenario. The unit circle is a good tool here as well.

You *could* come up with a formal approach for treating all equations of the type $\cos(ax-b)=0$. It'd be a good exercise. But memorizing the results in hopes of reapplying it isn't a useful way to approach related problem.

Perhaps you're interested in a formula that will solve *any* trigonometric equation? That'd be nice. Unfortunately, most equations in mathematics do not have neat algebraic solutions.